# Spyder: How to change Scope in Variable Explorer to show variables in defined functions, or even main()?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have many defined functions in my code. I also have a main() function where I call other functions to store values in variables. I want a record of all the variables that I have called thus far in main()? Currently it only shows global variables, so is there a way to change the environment or namespace that Variable explorer is referencing?